# Qlikview - multiple if in script

Tags: loops, qlikview

I have table:

[image]

I want to make in script to load data this:

```
 (if((color = 'blue' or color = 'green' or color = 'red') and place = 'A','GROUP A') or 
 if((color = 'yellow' or color = 'red' or color = 'blue') and place = 'B','GROUP B')) as allPl
```

but when create list my allPl is empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution, I think, will be

```
If(mixmatch(id,'blue','green','red') and place='A','Group A',
   If(mixmatch(id,'blue','green','yellow') and place='B','Group B')) as allPl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the `if` statements to get the result.

```
if( condition1 = true, result1,
  if(condition2 = true <at this point condition1 = false>, result2 ...
```

For your case:

```
 if(    color = 'blue' 
     or color = 'green' 
     or color = 'red','GROUP A',  
   if(   color = 'yellow' 
      or color = 'red' 
      or color = 'blue','GROUP B')
  ) as allPl
```

The script above will produce the following result:

[image]

But i'm not sure that this is the result you want. As you can see from the image above only the `yellow` value will have `GROUP B` assigned using this approach.

Leave a comment is this is the case

Comment: No, I want id 4, 5, 6 to be GROUP B, becase   I can't use nested if loop

Comment: Can you use `place` column as identification? For example just concatenate `place` value with `GROUP` string? Something like: `'GROUP ' &  place as appPl`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this solution.

```
map_allPl:
mapping
load
    color & '@@separator@@' &  place    AS IN
    ,allPl                              AS  OUT
inline
[color,place,allPl
blue,A,GROUP A
green,A,GROUP A
red,A,GROUP A
yellow,B,GROUP B
red,B,GROUP B
blue,B,GROUP B];

table:
load
    *
    ,applyMap('map_allPl',color & '@@separator@@' &  place,'nd')    AS  allPl
inline
[id,color,place
1,blue,A
2,green,A
3,red,A
4,yellow,B
5,red,B
6,blue,B
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with match() or wildmatch() or mixmatch() to reduce your expression.

try like,

if(match(color,'blue','green','red') and place='A','Group A',
if(match(color,'yellow','red','blue') and place='B','Group B')
) as appPl

Regards,

Comment: That was exactly my answer...please reply after you've read all the aswers